# Visual Studio 2015 EDMX model browser and diagram is missing

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

I have recently updated to Visual Studio 2015. Opened up my solution and works. Till I decided to add in an entity to my edmx. So I double-clicked on the edmx file to open the diagram like it should or maybe the model browser at least but it only opens an XML page. I checked any missed installation from the setup but didn't find anything about entity framework there. I tried to create a test solution and create another edmx but ADO.NET entity is  missing as well. What is going on? Am I going to revert back to Visual studio 2013?

Comment: try a re-install of VS https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6da25114-5830-4ad4-a152-ec92c84b1466/designer-for-edmx-missing?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: did u check this `First, open up the EDMX file. Then, in main menu select View > Other Windows > Entity Data Model Browser (it usually opens in the same panel as Solution explorer).`

Comment: @Webruster Yes, its like the model browser never exists. I'm repairing VS2015 right now.

Comment: It is still not showing the edmx designer even after repairing. I need help

Answer (score 33):

For me, the sequence was:

- Double-click the .edmx file
- Right click any white space in the opened diagram
- Click Model Browser in the context menu that appears

If it opens as XML then it means that eventually XML Text Editor is set as default program to open edmx file. You can follow these steps to open in ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer

- right click on your edmx file
- and select open with and select the option as show in below image.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/D49Ki.png

Comment: I dont get the ado.net option.

Comment: @J.P Masangcay : please mark answer if this resolve your problem.

Comment: is there any possibility  to open model browser directely whihtout openning EDMX

Answer (score 6):

Alternate solution as the upvoted answer didn't work for me in VS2017:

Under the menu bar ribbon -

1. Select 'View'
2. Select 'Other Windows'
3. Select 'Entity Data Model Browser'

Comment: I haven't this window